# How can I get Apple Watch style Activity reminders on iPhone / iPad

Tags: ios, notifications, reminders, watchos, activity.app

Example: watchOS reminds users to that it’s “Time to stand!”.

Is there any way to leverage the default apps *provided by Apple* to get these notifications on iOS devices?

The default reminders app is a bit too tedious for this and 3rd party apps seem to require you to open them regularly to prevent their notifications from being disabled.

Preferably, this can be accomplished without owning an Apple Watch, but I'll accept an answer which requires one if no other options exist.

Comment: I think this is not possible on the iPhone with the default installed apps. Only way to get these notifications seems to be on an Apple Watch.

Answer (score 1):

For now I think you'll have to get an Apple watch or look into 3rd party apps.

Comment: Can you add a bit of info about what you tried that led you to this answer?

Comment: It's not a feature of the OS unfortunately. There's no way to set up reminders or any other default iOS app to detect when you've been sitting for too long, for instance. A third party app would be the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement this on iOS without 3rd party-apps.

There seems to be a good third-party app [here.](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/stand-up-the-work-break-timer/id828244687?mt=8)

This reminds you to stand at your office. It is free. You cm get custom alarms at your office location and you can set when you want to stand up in intervals.

There is also another app [here.](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/stand-up-reminder-and-timer/id1196457882?mt=8) This is similar to the other app, but this one doesn't seem to be as popular.